# Matplotlib and OpenCV are causing a crash

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, conda

I have installed both `OpenCV` and `Matplotlib` from `conda-forge` channel. When I use the the following code I get an error.

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow('bam', 0)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
cv2.namedWindow('bam bam', 0)
```

The error is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. To reproduce this error create a new `python 3.6` environment in Anaconda. And install both `OpenCV` and `Matplotlib` in this order. I have tried searching in various forums but I couldn't find this sort of error. I would be greatful if someone could help me resolve this.

Comment: I tried it with python2 it works fine. I did not test it on python3. It is strange that it gives error on python3 and not python2

Comment: Strange thing is it's working on my home workstation but it's not working on my work workstation. I've reinstalled anaconda I've tried all iterations. Could you give it a try with python 3, please.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem although with python 3.5. What resolved the issue for me was to install OpenCV via conda-forge after installing matplotlib via pip in the conda envrionment. That way conda won't try to downgrade matplotlib to 2.3.3 when installing opencv.

What worked for me was:

```
activate env
pip install matplotlib
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```